# From MongoDB convert from dictionary to row with Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mongodb

This is a test coming from MongoDB, I need to convert to MySQL. But! Sometimes there is more then one "agents", if that's the case I need each agent on their own row and that agent should have the same "display_name". For example Walter should have Gloria on one row and Barb on next and both have Walt Mosley under "display_name".

```
  [{'name': 'Loomis, Gloria',
  'primaryemail': 'gloria@gmail.com',
  'primaryphone': '212-382-1121'},
 {'name': 'Hogson, Barb',
  'primaryemail': 'bho124@aol.com',
  'primaryphone': ''}]
```

[image]

I've tried this but it just splits out the key/values.

```
a,b,c = [[d[e] for d in test] for e in sorted(test[0].keys())]
print(a,b,c)
```

This is the original JSON format:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('58e6ececafb08d6'),
  'item_type': 'Contributor',
  'role': 0,
  'short_bio': 'Walter Mosley (b. 1952)',
  'firebrand_id': 1588,
  'display_name': 'Walter Mosley',
  'first_name': 'Walter',
  'last_name': 'Mosley',
  'slug': 'walter-mosley',
  'updated': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 7, 8, 17, 11, 926000),
  'image': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/8588-book-contributor.jpg',
  'social_media_name': '',
  'social_media_link': '',
  'website': '',
  'agents': [{'name': 'Loomis, Gloria',
    'primaryemail': 'gloria@gmail.com',
    'primaryphone': '212-382-1121'},
   {'name': 'Hogson, Barb',
    'primaryemail': 'bho124@aol.com',
    'primaryphone': ''}],
  'estates': [],
  'deleted': False}
```

Comment: For that you don't need to do anything in code, if you're getting that result from a MongoDB aggregation query, then at the end add this stage :: `{$unwind : '$agents'}`

Comment: @srinivasy I don't have access to MongoDB, just working on the JSON file from Mongo and I'm hoping there is a way I can do this in Python

Comment: This is do-able and pretty straightforward, but the solution depends on the original format of your json. Instead of posting only the list in the 'agents' field, can you post (a subset) of your json? With that, I can help.

Comment: @OriolMirosa that's great news! I've just edited my post to include the entire json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've an array of dictionaries from your JSON file, try this :

**JSON input :**

```
inputJSON = [{'item_type': 'Contributor',
            'role': 0,
            'short_bio': 'Walter Mosley (b. 1952)',
            'firebrand_id': 1588,
            'display_name': 'Walter Mosley',
            'first_name': 'Walter',
            'last_name': 'Mosley',
            'slug': 'walter-mosley',
            'image': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/8588-book-contributor.jpg',
            'social_media_name': '',
            'social_media_link': '',
            'website': '',
            'agents': [{'name': 'Loomis, Gloria',
                        'primaryemail': 'gloria@gmail.com',
                        'primaryphone': '212-382-1121'},
                       {'name': 'Hogson, Barb',
                        'primaryemail': 'bho124@aol.com',
                        'primaryphone': ''}],
            'estates': [],
            'deleted': False}]
```

**Code :**

```
import copy 

finalJSON = []

for each in inputJSON:
    for agnt in each.get('agents'):
        newObj = copy.deepcopy(each)
        newObj['agents'] = agnt
        finalJSON.append(newObj)

print(finalJSON)
```

Comment: I'm getting: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when I try your code. How can I fix this?

Comment: @LunaLoveDove : What did you get when you print each ? Are you able to see agents array in each?

Comment: never mind it worked, I just needed to make an Exception. Thank you!